# Subitems in Shell Flyout in .Net MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am working with .Net MAUI (Shell app) and need to create a [Flyout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-6.0) with sub-items like this:

[image]

I search for the solution across official documentation and related samples but didn't find any. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: In XF Shell there was no way to do this when it was first released, so I used FlyoutPage with ListView to achieve this, not sure if Shell has the same issue still or not but from the first look my guess is it still does

Comment: The Flyout in MAUI doesn't have a method to make subitems, but you can use the 'IsVisible' to make the lable disappear or appear. You can refer to this [show flyout (shell) with submenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/203335/show-flyout-shell-with-submenu.html). This might be a workaround for now.

Comment: I end up using FlyoutPage instead, thanks for the comments, guys :)

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**

The Flyout in MAUI doesn't have a method to make subitems, but you can use the 'IsVisible' to make the lable disappear or appear.

You can refer to this [show flyout (shell) with submenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/203335/show-flyout-shell-with-submenu.html). This might be a workaround for now.

Comment: I tried this solution before creating the question and it didn't work (at least until November 2022). If I use Xamarin it's OK, but not OK for .Net MAUI